# AngularJS combining objects in array on properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have a large array of objects (1500+) and the objects match on one of the properties. So the overall number of objects could be reduced e.g. for better performance in ng-repeat.
I'm kind of new to AngularJS and JS itself, so help is much appreciated!

**my Array of Objects (simplified)**

```
myArray = [
    {
        "role": "user111",
        "operation": "create",
        "concept": "folder"
    },
    {
        "role": "user111",
        "operation": "create",
        "concept": "task"
    },
    {
        "role": "user111",
        "operation": "delete",
        "concept": "task"
    },
    {
        "role": "user222",
        "operation": "create",
        "concept": "folder"
    },
    {
        "role": "user222",
        "operation": "create",
        "concept": "task"
    },
    {
        "role": "user222",
        "operation": "delete",
        "concept": "task"
    }
]
```

**desired Output**

```
dreamArray = [
    {
        "role": "user111",
        "operation": {
               "create": ["folder", "task"],
               "delete": ["task"]
                      }
    },
    {
        "role": "user222",
        "operation": {
                   "create": ["folder", "task"],
                   "delete": ["task"]
                      }
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you always receive your object sorted on the `role` property like in your example data? If so that's a valuable information and can greatly simplify the code.

Comment: @Redu in fact I do! How would this simplify things?

Comment: Well then you can do this just in O(n) time by using a single `.reduce()` operation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `forEach()` loop and `thisArg` parameter.

```js
var myArray = [{"role":"user111","operation":"create","concept":"folder"},{"role":"user111","operation":"create","concept":"task"},{"role":"user111","operation":"delete","concept":"task"},{"role":"user222","operation":"create","concept":"folder"},{"role":"user222","operation":"create","concept":"task"},{"role":"user222","operation":"delete","concept":"task"}]

var result = [];
myArray.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.role]) {
   this[e.role] = {role: e.role, operation: {[e.operation]: [e.concept]}}
    result.push(this[e.role]);
  } else {
    var op = this[e.role].operation[e.operation]
    if(op) op.push(e.concept)
    else this[e.role].operation[e.operation] = [e.concept]
  }
}, Object.create(null))


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a hash table and store the reference to the groups.

```js
var array = [{ role: "user111", operation: "create", concept: "folder" }, { role: "user111", operation: "create", concept: "task" }, { role: "user111", operation: "delete", concept: "task" }, { role: "user222", operation: "create", concept: "folder" }, { role: "user222", operation: "create", concept: "task" }, { role: "user222", operation: "delete", concept: "task" }],
    grouped = array.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, o) {
            if (!hash[o.role]) {
                hash[o.role] = {};
                r.push({ role: o.role, operation: hash[o.role]});
            }
            hash[o.role][o.operation] = hash[o.role][o.operation] || [];
            hash[o.role][o.operation].push(o.concept);
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce()` and `find()`

```
var myArray = [{ role: "user111", operation: "create", concept: "folder" }, { role: "user111", operation: "create", concept: "task" }, { role: "user111", operation: "delete", concept: "task" }, { role: "user222", operation: "create", concept: "folder" }, { role: "user222", operation: "create", concept: "task" }, { role: "user222", operation: "delete", concept: "task" }],

const dreamArray = myArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let obj = acc.find(e => e.role === item.role);
  if(!obj){
    obj = {"role" : item.role, "operation": {[item.operation]: [item.concept]}};
    acc.push(obj);
  }else{
    obj.operation[item.operation] = obj.operation[item.operation] || [];
    obj.operation[item.operation].push(item.concept);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(dreamArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in my comment, if you happen to receive the data already sorted on the `role` property (which you say so) then the required operation boils down to a very simple `.reduce()` operation and can be implemented with O(n) time complexity as follows;

```js
var data   = [{"role":"user111","operation":"create","concept":"folder"},{"role":"user111","operation":"create","concept":"task"},{"role":"user111","operation":"delete","concept":"task"},{"role":"user222","operation":"create","concept":"folder"},{"role":"user222","operation":"create","concept":"task"},{"role":"user222","operation":"delete","concept":"task"}],
    result = data.reduce((r,c,i) => !i || r[r.length-1].role !== c.role ? r.concat({"role": c.role, "operation": c.operation === "create" ? {"create": [c.concept], "delete": []}
                                                                                                                                          : {"create": [], "delete": [c.concept]}})
                                                                        : r[r.length-1].operation[c.operation].includes(e => e === c.concept) ? r
                                                                                                                                              :(r[r.length-1].operation[c.operation].push(c.concept),r), []);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```